# How to generate Ethereum address in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is the script to generate Ethereum address in Node.JS

> **How can i use the below script in Flutter to generate Ethereum address?**

```
    const hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed); // used bip39 to get seed
    const itsMyWallet = hdwallet.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0").getWallet();

    console.log(`Address: ${itsMyWallet.getAddressString()}`);
    console.log(`Private Key: ${itsMyWallet.getPrivateKeyString()}`);
```

I know how to generated mnemonic in flutter with bip39 package, some coding part i have added below,
**Problem is i am not getting ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey package in flutter packages**

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use a flutter package for Ethereum known as `ethereum 4.0.1` which can be found [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ethereum). It may have what you are looking for, but if it doesn't it is because it is still currently in development, but it does implement most of the standard Ethereum api's

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [gist](https://gist.github.com/its-VSP/237171155fdbaa0a6ced098eef45a728)

Basically it will

1. Convert the privateKey to bigInt
2. Extract PublicKey
3. addressDigest = keccak256(publicKey)
4. address = last 20 bytes of addressDigest

You can also use my [toChecksumAddress](https://gist.github.com/its-VSP/c20add0e3ddae576abe847e56d99c9f7) gist to convert above address to checksumAddress